# Drag and drop a tab onto a single-tab, no-tab-bar window

Tags: xcode, macos, tabs, appkit

I'm adding tabbing to my application by means of [this reference implementation](https://github.com/DivineDominion/NSWindow-Tabbing). It works perfectly, but there is one extra piece of functionality I'd like to add.

Drag and drop of tabs between windows is currently only possible if the target window's tab bar is visible. This usually means that the target window already has multiple tabs, as the tab bar on single-tab windows is hidden by default. This means a tab can generally not be easily moved to another window that isn't already tabbed.

Maybe what I'm asking for isn't particularly correct / idiomatic behavior, as apps like Terminal have the same limitation. On the other hand Finder and Safari *do* allow for single-tab, no-tab-bar windows to receive tabs via drag and drop and I find that rather useful.

Does anyone have an idea how one could go about receiving tabs regardless of tab bar status?

Comment: In Terminal and TextEdit: If the all windows have a tab bar then a new window also has a tabbar. Is a permanent tab bar a solution?

Comment: Whether a new window in those apps has a tab bar depends on whether the "Show Tab Bar" menu item is enabled. I prefer to have it disabled but a permanent tab bar would work, of course. It's ultimately not a big thing but I think it's telling that Finder and Safari opted to not require the tab bar. Don't really understand why that isn't the default behavior.

Comment: Whether a new window has a tab bar does not depend on whether the "Show Tab Bar" menu item is enabled. The menu item can be disabled or hidden. Maybe the tab bar behaviour of Safari isn't compatible with existing windows. I don't think it's possible to replicate this behaviour without implementing your own tabs.

Comment: We must be talking about different things here. I was talking about the specific example of Terminal and TextEdit, both of which have a "Show Tab Bar" menu item, the state of which determines how a new window behaves. A custom implementation could choose to not provide such an option and just always show the tab bar if one wanted to do so. I don't.

Comment: Yes, we are talking about different things. I thought a permanent tab bar was an acceptable easy solution.